# Does closeness in total variation distance imply closeness in moments?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables such that the distribution of $X$ is the $\chi^2$-distribution of degree $k$ and the distribution of $Y$ is close to that of $X$ in total variation distance $\delta$. Then what can we say about upper bound of their moment difference, i.e.,
$$
\left|\mathbb{E}\left[X^m\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y^m\right]\right|?
$$

I think a $\chi^2$-distribution is concentrated so their moment difference should be small if $\delta$ is small enough, but I am not sure how to show the moments are close, even for small $m$. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the total variation norm does not imply that moments are close. Let $f$ be the density of $X$ and let $g$ be any other probability density function. Let $Y$ be the random variable with pdf $(1-\frac{\delta}{2})f(x) + \frac{\delta}{2} g(x).$ Then for any measurable set $A$,
$$
|P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A)|=\bigg|\int_A f(x)dx - \int_A (1-\frac{\delta}{2})f(x) + \frac{\delta}{2} g(x)dx\bigg| \leq \frac{\delta}{2}\int_A f(x) + \frac{\delta}{2}\int_A g(x) \leq \delta. $$

On the other hand, we can choose $g$ arbitrarily here, so in particular we can take to be the density function of any random variable with no finite moments, in which case the difference in your question is infinite for all $m$.